# Membership create user providerError

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership, vb.net-2010

i have an application that uses membership schema 6.

When i try to add a user on code behind with membership.CreateUser i get error 11 "Provider error".

In my application Membership.UserValidate, Membership.GetUser, Membership.ChangePassword etc. work fine.

Even Role.AddUserToRole works fine without having created the user.

I have the following settings in the web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider"> 
  <providers> 
    <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" /> 
    <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" 

         applicationName="/myApp" description="MySQL myApp" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="True" 

         enablePasswordRetrieval="True" enablePasswordReset="True" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="False" requiresUniqueEmail="True" passwordFormat="Encrypted" 

         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" /> 
  </providers> 
</membership>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Does it say anything more in the error message? What data do you use to call the method?

Comment: i do not get error message since membership does not returns exceptions. I only get status = 11 that means ProviderError.

Comment: This is my call: Membership.CreateUser(newUsernameTextBox.Text, newUserPasswordTextBox.Text, newUserEmailTextBox.Text, newUserQuestionTextBox.Text, newUserAnswerTextBox.Text, True, status)

Comment: I meant the values? is your password long enough? is the email valid? You say AddUserToRole works for a user that does not exist? Does it work for an existing user?

Comment: Yes, password and email are in correct format. If they weren't the status would have been different (2 and 5 accordingly). All the rest functions of membership work fine. I can log in/out, change my password and email and add role to a user. thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm a bit at a loss. What's in the database? And what happens if you set writeExceptionsToEventLog to true? Any thing in the event viewer? We use a custom provider, so we can track everything that happens...

Answer (score 0):

I got the error because I added columns to one of the created membership tables.  After removing the columns all worked fine.

Comment: Yeah, don't do that... never do that.  Instead, create a separate table with a 1:1 relationship on the primary key.